# FormatNumber - How to hide comma as decimal seperator?

Tags: excel

OK this is really bugging me now.
We use comma as decimal seperator and I want to hide it if decimals are 0.
How do you do that?
For example for number: '15.213.122,00'
I would like to show just '15.213.122' and not '15.213.122,'
`#.###,##` Doesn't work. This might work for english muberics tho: `#,###.##`

Comment: Use conditional formatting.

Comment: I don't want to apply conditional formatting just for this. It will screw up my program. Is this excel bug or something? I also noticed that VBA actually uses . for decimal separation while excel uses ,. It's a bit conflicting.

Comment: The various formats available for Excel worksheets are documented. So no, it is not a bug. I would classify it as a feature you desire which has not been implemented. I don't know of another method of implementing that feature other than conditional formatting. Why should the number format of a cell "screw up your program"?

Comment: For excel you can specify what character defines decimal place or 1000th. But it doesn't use those characters in numberformat. So basically only english users that use '.' for decimal places benefit from this. In fact if you used #,###.## it shouldn't just erase "." from numberformat.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does it for you if you set the formatting to "General". Unless you want some special format, which requires something else.